# How should i get previous selected option automatically in dropdown in javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript, in a dropdown menu if we select one option and in that dropdown how can I get a dropdown option which had selected previous option automatically on current option (if that current option fails on certain condition).

Comment: You should store the previous selected option in a variable and use that to update the dropdown incase of a failure or to update the variable with the newly selected value if the condition satisfies

Comment: Always disappointing when you put lots of effort into an answer to get absolutely no response

Answer (score 1):

As you've already discovered, there is no way to get the previously selected value when the dropdown is changed directly from the dropdown itself.

The best option is to store the currently selected value, my preference is via a `data-` attribute.

So if for example you have a select like the following...

```
<select>
  <option value="1" selected>One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

You would include the currently selected value as a `data-previousvalue` attribute... this would be part of the code that creates the control in the first place...

```
<select data-previousvalue="1">
  <option value="1" selected>One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Then when you change the select, you can check at the current value and if necessary reset it back to that stored one.

In the following example, if you select the third item `Three (bad)` it will automatically take you back to the previously selected option...

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // Get the dropdown
  var dd = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  // When the dropdown changes
  dd.addEventListener("change", function(){
    // If it's a bad one
    if (dd.value == "3") {
      // Reselect the previous value
      dd.value = dd.getAttribute("data-previousvalue");
    }
    // Now store the value for the next time
    dd.setAttribute("data-previousvalue", dd.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<select data-previousvalue="4">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three (bad)</option>
  <option value="4" selected>Four</option>
</select>
```

And if you have jquery available...

```js
$(function(){
  $("select").on("change", function(){
    var $dd = $(this);
    // If it's a bad one
    if ($dd.val() == "3") {
      // Reselect the previous value
      $dd.val($dd.data("previousvalue"));
    }
    // Now store the value for the next time
    $dd.data("previousvalue", $dd.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-previousvalue="4">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three (bad)</option>
  <option value="4" selected>Four</option>
</select>
```

---

If you can't add the data attribute to the control at the point of render, then you can also set it on the page load...

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // Get the dropdown
  var dd = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  // Set the currently selected value into the attribute
  dd.setAttribute("data-previousvalue", dd.value);
  // When the dropdown changes
  dd.addEventListener("change", function(){
    // If it's a bad one
    if (dd.value == "3") {
      // Reselect the previous value
      dd.value = dd.getAttribute("data-previousvalue");
    }
    // Now store the value for the next time
    dd.setAttribute("data-previousvalue", dd.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three (bad)</option>
  <option value="4" selected>Four</option>
</select>
```

If you have jquery available to you...

```js
$(function(){
  $("select")
    .each(function(i,v) {
      var $dd = $(this);
      $dd.data("previousvalue", $dd.val());
    })
    .on("change", function(){
      var $dd = $(this);
      // If it's a bad one
      if ($dd.val() == "3") {
        // Reselect the previous value
        $dd.val($dd.data("previousvalue"));
      }
      // Now store the value for the next time
      $dd.data("previousvalue", $dd.val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three (bad)</option>
  <option value="4" selected>Four</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it setting `element.val(previousStatus)`

```js
// Your changing value should assign on adStatus
// May be its come from database(previous status) or depends on user activity
let adStatus = 'Unfriendly';
$('#AdblockType').val(`${adStatus}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="AdblockType">
  <option value="Friendly">Friendly</option>
  <option vlaue="Unfriendly">Unfriendly</option>
</select>
```